# TypeError: inputs.lineItems is undefined React

Tags: reactjs

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
  taxRate: 0.00,
  lineItems: [
    {
      id: 'initial',
      name: '',
      description: '',
      quantity: 0,
      price: 0.00,
    },
  ]
});
 function handleInvoiceChange(e) {
    //setInputs(inputs => ({...inputs,[e.target.name]: e.target.value}));
    setInputs({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
  }

const calcLineItemsTotal = (event) => {
  return inputs.lineItems.reduce((prev, cur) => (prev + (cur.quantity * cur.price)), 0)
}

  const calcTaxTotal = () => {
    return calcLineItemsTotal() + (inputs.taxRate / 100)
  }
```

and this is how i handle the change

```
const handleLineItemChange = (elementIndex) => (event) => {
    let lineItems = inputs.lineItems.map((item, i) => {
      if (elementIndex !== i) return item
      return {...item, [event.target.name]: event.target.value}
    })
    setInputs(inputs => ({...inputs,[lineItems]:lineItems}));
   //setInputs({lineItems})
  }

  const handleAddLineItem = (event) => {
    setInputs({

      lineItems: inputs.lineItems.concat(
        [{ id: uuidv4(), name: '', description: '', quantity: 0, price: 0.00 }]
      )
    })
  }



const handleRemoveLineItem = (elementIndex) => (event) => {
  
     setInputs({
          lineItems: inputs.lineItems.filter((item, i) => {
            return elementIndex !== i
          })
        })
      }
```

this is a react application of an invoice generator the problem occures when i add the taxrate then i get that error

Comment: Is there a call to `setInputs` anywhere in the component?  Is it setting a value that doesn't have a `lineItems` property?  (Or are you directly mutating `inputs` anywhere?)

Comment: If you are updating your state inputs anywhere,how are you doing it?

Comment: please modify your question and include the full component , as the comment above mentions you are probably mutating the state or updating the state with a value that does not include ``lineItems ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated values to states with hooks are not merged but replaced**.

Also if you are using a version of v16 or lower of react know that Synthetic event is pooled by react, i.e event object is cleared before state callback runs.

[`Check here`](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-event-pooling.html) for more information.

> The SyntheticEvent objects are pooled. This means that the
> SyntheticEvent object will be reused and all properties will be
> nullified after the event handler has been called.

The correct way to update your state is as below where you use function way to update state and copy the event values you need to separate variables outside of the setInputs function call

```
const name = e.target.name;
const value = e.target.value;
setInputs(inputs => ({...inputs,[name]: value}));
```

The rest of your function updates will be as below

```
 const handleAddLineItem = (event) => {
    setInputs(input => ({
      ...input,
      lineItems: inputs.lineItems.concat(
        [{ id: uuidv4(), name: '', description: '', quantity: 0, price: 0.00 }]
      )
    }));
  }



const handleRemoveLineItem = (elementIndex) => (event) => {
  
     setInputs(input =>({
          ...input,
          lineItems: inputs.lineItems.filter((item, i) => {
            return elementIndex !== i
          })
     }));
 }
```

Comment: thank you so i assume this one is wrong too

Comment: const handleLineItemChange = (elementIndex) => (event) => {
    let lineItems = inputs.lineItems.map((item, i) => {
      if (elementIndex !== i) return item
      return {...item, [event.target.name]: event.target.value}
    })
    setInputs(inputs => ({...inputs,[lineitems]:lineItems}));
  }

Comment: and sorry i dont know how to use the website well so i didnt know how to write the code

Comment: yes, you are right, I updated my post for it too